# AES/CBC/PKCS#5 cookie decryption in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, ldap, aes

We are currently using web based LDAP for authentication and part of the process is to decrypt a cookie.  In the past we have used the ColdFusion code below.

```
<cffile action="read" file="e:\keys\key.cfm" variable="thekey">
<cfset clearcookie = decrypt(evaluate("cookie.#[registered app name]#"), thekey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding', 'base64')>
```

We now need to do the same in PHP but for some reason my code does not seem to be working.  My cookie is currently saved under `$ck` and the key under `$key` and I do not have an IV which I hope is not needed.

Per a post by lord_t and Sage Pay Support, I am doing the following:

```
$ck = substr($ck,1);
$ck = base64_decode($ck);
$text= (mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ck, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$key));
echo $text;
```

When I run it my output is garbage which leads me to believe the algorithm is not right.  What could be the issue?  Do I need and IV?

Again, I want to replicate what we have done in ColdFusion in the past.

Comment: Where is your ColdFusion code?

Comment: Sorry! Just added the code.